# Building a scalable Email Delivery system

Tags: scalability, email, rdbms

I want to fix my current Email Delivery system which sends email using a third-party email provider and creates a record for each email sent in RDS. Functionally this is how the system behaves -

- A user creates Campaign to send emails to their leads. A campaign can be sent to up to 1 million users
- A created campaign is stored in a table called `campaign`. The table also stores information of leads (JSON condition) to whom email needs to be sent
- A job runs which polls `campaign` table and calculates actual leads from the JSON conditon and retrieves their email addresses from `lead` table
- Multiple instances of this job run depending on the number of pending(queued) campaigns
- A new thread picks the list obtained in the above step and sends the emails in bulk of 50 emails using third party email service provider API
- For each email sent a record in `Email` table is created. The table stores the information of sender and receiver along with the status of the email. The table also has relation to `campaign` table
- The information of email bounces are received using a webhook and status of such emails are set to "bounced" in `Email` table
- The email table is used to build different kinds of reports like finding the leads to whom the email was sent using a particular campaign by some particular user
- The columns of `Email` table are indexed because it is heavily read across multiple parts of the application. Due to this writes to the table have become slower
- In case many emails are queued for processing and multiple jobs are spawned, writes on the `Email` table becomes a bottleneck, which causes replication lag and impacts reports at various places

My goal is to make inserts and reads on `Email` table faster which is not possible using RDS.

Is there any other way I can use to scale this system with the capability to send millions of emails?

I see Elastic Search as one option for storing `Email` table. Since Elastic Search is not a primary data store I need to build applications to sync this data to a persistent storage. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: youre saying you can send emails to a api over the internet faster than you can insert them into your database?

Comment: @Ewan It sounds weird but yes that's what happens in this case. It is also a function of a number of records in the table.When the number of records is more than 10 million then inserting a record into it makes the indexes to be rebuilt causing page faults to increase and ultimately slowing down the inserts.

Comment: Consider asking this on a database SE, as this is most likely just a question of tuning your databse.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like its the reports that are slowing you down.

Move all reporting to a datawarehouse on a separate box.

If that doesn't solve it.

Split the app so that different campaigns are run on separate databases.

Comment: It is the inserts which are slowing down the system. Also splitting the campaign across multiple database won't serve the purpose as the reports are built across campaigns

Comment: if you didnt have the reports, how mamy indexes would you need?

Comment: In that case, just a clustered index on the primary key would have served the purpose

Comment: making your inserts faster right?

Comment: Yes, but reports will suffer..

Comment: An argument could be said for not saving the e-mail contents directly in the database, or at least not in the table causing the bottleneck.  Searching through such a table from a database perspective means loading all that content from the disk just to compare fields which may not even include the content itself.  Consider creating a one-to-one table to another containing the e-mail content.

Comment: reports will actually improve if you move them to a data warehouse as i suggest. You have the situation back to front. there is no reason a standard rdms cant support your insert and update scenario. Its doing the reporting on your transactional database which is the mistake you are making

Answer (score 0):

You could be successful by distributing the work with the Email table over separate tables.

Create one table e.g. `EmailWork` that has all information what email is sent to whom.

Create a second table e.g. `EmailStatus` that is empty at first, and that takes all the writing stuff. If mail sender status information drops in, fails, bumps etc - everything goes there.

The second table could act as, so to say, "stream". Once a row have been worked, it is deleted.

`EmailWorkInfo` could be indexed in in order to read fast. `EmailStatus` could be lightweight as possible, therefore having no indizes.

Now you can control the workload. Iterate slowly through `EmailStatus`, take an info, search in `EmailWork` and update.  Remove the row in `EmailStatus` once you have been successful. Wait updating, if it becomes too much. Wait sending further, if the second table becomes too big.

Another approach would be to have one separate table only for the report.

I cannot know which is best as I don't know the details. However, my suggestion is to check if the workload can be distributed over different tables, and then to control how they are worked.